# ES6 Detection in WebStorm Broken in Project

Tags: intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I had WebStorm set up to recognize ES6, but something happened recently and now it doesn't recognize my files as ES6.  `File -> Default Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> JavaScript` is set to `ECMAScript6` and in the actual project file if I go to `Use JavaScript Library`, `ECMAScript6` is selected.

Does anyone know what's going on and why this might have happened? Any easy fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript version chosen in `File -> Default Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> JavaScript` only affects new projects.
For current project, you need to make sure to set appropriate language version in `Settings(Preferences) -> Languages and Frameworks -> JavaScript`

Comment: Thanks for answering! Where is `Settings(Preferences)`?  I don't see that?

Comment: On Windows/Linux, it's File | Settings; on MacOSX, it's WebStorm | Preferences. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/accessing-settings.html